# Measurement Protocol ответ на запрос GIF89a�����,D;

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

Передаю данные о транзакции на сайте в Google Аналитику через Measurement Protocol:

```
    $tid = "UA-17567****-1";
    $data = array(
        'v' => 1, //Версия протокола
        'tid' => $tid, //Идентификатор отслеживания/идентификатор веб-ресурса
        'cid' => 79122, //Идентификатор клиента
        't' => 'transaction' //event //Тип обращения
    );
    
    $data['ti'] = '0МВР-011744'; //Идентификатор транзакции
    $data['tr'] = '100.5'; //Доход от транзакции
    
    //$url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
    $url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect';
    $content = http_build_query($data);
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
    $user_agent = 'Example/1.0 (http://example.com/)';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Если отправлять данные через дебаг `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect` - я получаю ответ что всё норм:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [
    {
      "valid": true,
      "parserMessage": [
        
      ],
      "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-175679946-1&cid=79122&t=transaction&ti=0МВР-011744&tr=100.5"
    }
  ],
  "parserMessage": [
    {
      "messageType": "INFO",
      "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
    }
  ]
}
```

Если отправлять на бой `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` - то получаю в ответ:

```
GIF89a�����,D;
```

Как мне интерпретировать этот ответ? В идеале мне нужно получить ответ что данные успешно добавлены или код ошибки если не успешно.

Comment: Как интерпретировать ответ всё ещё не понятно, но данные успешно отправляются в Google Аналитику. Предположу что это ответ об успешном отправлении

Answer (score -1):

в запросе не хватает User-Agent,
здесь описано решение:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-measurement-protocol/c/VVaoSU-2FB4?pli=1